Attempt to send message from Azure Function to Azure SignalR fails with 403 forbidden
I'm using Azure SignalR in serverless mode. I've an Azure Function which receives events from Event Hub and sends messages to Azure SignalR.
[Function(nameof(EventHubEventsHandler))]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "userevents", ConnectionStringSetting = "SignalRConnectionSetting")]
public async Task<List<SignalRMessageAction>> Run([EventHubTrigger("userschanged", Connection = "EventHubConnectionSetting")] EventData[] events)

{
    var messages = new List<SignalRMessageAction>();
    foreach (EventData @event in events)
    {
        try
        {
           messages.Add(new SignalRMessageAction("userChanged")
           {
               Arguments = new[] { "user changed" },
           });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    return messages;
}

The connection string SignalRConnectionSetting in Azure Function App settings is defined like Endpoint=https://xxx.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=yyy;Version=1.0;
Azure Function is triggered successfully, but in Application Insights I see that the attempt to send message to Azure SignalR fails with 403 forbidden.
What I see in the logs:
GET https://xxx.service.signalr.net/api/v1/auth/accessKey
Result code: 200

POST https://xxx.service.signalr.net/api/hubs/userevents/:send?api-version=2022-06-01
Result code: 403

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Exception while executing function: Functions.EventHubEventsHandler Azure SignalR service runtime error. Request Uri: https://xxx.service.signalr.net/api/hubs/userevents/:send?api-version=2022-06-01 Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden) 

I've no clue what can be wrong.

Are you able to execute the function locally as my function works perfectly post deploying too?

While executing it locally, use live trace tool in SignalR to see the incoming messages

After deploying the function code, are you able to see this

@IkhtesamAfrin I see the key signalr_extension. I've tried live trace tool, but even if it is enabled, it shows me 'Not Ready' and I don't see any incoming messages.

enable it and then click on save like this, once it is done it will be ready to show you the logs

@IkhtesamAfrin Yes, that's what I have done. I was waiting for 30 minutes and it was still Not Ready.

If you have opened the trace tool before saving and later you saved it then it will show you not ready. Try to save and then open or refresh. It should work for you as it did for me


Refresh the Signal R and Event Hub Connection strings and update the new values in the Application settings.
Make sure you have enabled Public Access in all the services.

Follow below steps to achieve your requirement.

Created a EventHub Trigger Azure function to receive events from EventHub and send the messages to signal R.

Code Snippet:
[Function(nameof(EventHubEventsHandler))]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "userevents", ConnectionStringSetting = "SignalRConnectionSetting")]
public async Task<List<SignalRMessageAction>> Run([EventHubTrigger("kpeventhub", Connection = "EventHubConnectionString")] EventData[] events)
{
    var messages = new List<SignalRMessageAction>();
    foreach (EventData @event in events)
    {
        try
        {
            messages.Add(new SignalRMessageAction("userChanged")
            {
                Arguments = new[] { "user changed" },
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while processing the event data.");
        }
    }
    return messages;
}


Created a Signal R service and configured with Event Hub.
Enabled Application Insights in the Azure function app.
Added below Application Settings in the Function App=>Environment Variables:

"EventHubConnectionString": "Endpoint=sb://<eventhubnamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=y8TjnnTJA2XXXXXX7+AEhJudoTs=",
"SignalRConnectionSetting": "Endpoint=https://<signalr>.service.signalr.net;AccessKey=0vSNRXjzPnyQTQXXXXXnNZtC5pp8=;Version=1.0;"


Enable Live Trace in Signal R service=>Monitoring:



Sending the Events:


Function App Invocations:

Live Trace:


Logs in Application Insights:


